# SOAP-UI Http Status: 405 - The HTTP method 'GET' of the incoming request... is not allowed

Tags: rest, wcf, soapui

I'm doing a POST from SOAP-UI to a IIS C# REST/JSON web service. I had it working, then changed my web.config to require SSL and this problem began. 
Also changed IIS webservice to SSL required instead of accepted.

Now I'm getting the error in RAW view of SOAP-UI:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: POST
Content-Length: 1565
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
```

From Trace Listener:

```
    <ExceptionString>System.InvalidOperationException: The HTTP method 'GET' of the incoming request (with URI 'https://mysite/MyApp/SQRTREST.svc/placeOrderSQRT/') is not allowed.</ExceptionString>
<StackTrace>   at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.WriteExceptionToTraceString(XmlTextWriter xml, Exception exception, Int32 remainingLength, Int32 remainingAllowedRecursionDepth)
   at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.ExceptionToTraceString(Exception exception, Int32 maxTraceStringLength)
   at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.GetSerializedPayload(Object source, TraceRecord traceRecord, Exception exception, Boolean getServiceReference)
   at System.Runtime.TraceCore.HandledExceptionWarning(EtwDiagnosticTrace trace, String param0, Exception exception)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HttpUnhandledOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp;amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
```

So if SOAP-UI is doing a POST, why is the error related to an HTTP "GET" method?

This is happening in with SOAP-UI in Production too, but yet the external client seems to still be able to call the webservice using whatever software they are using.

I see other posts about 405 on StackOveflow, but nothing that addresses a SOAP-UI post.

Updates on next day after posting the above:

1) I got setup with Debug/Trace - and when running SOAP-UI, the trace never enters the method

2) I set up a C# client program that does the Post, and it does get into the method and I'm able to use Debug/Trace (it's ending with another issue I have to untangle).

Update 2: Some research makes me think it might have to do with the fact that the HTTP Headers are encrypted.  Someone in the SOAP-Ui forum mentioned having a missing HTTP Header; but not sure where that leads me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lead me to the solution:

[https://forums.iis.net/t/1152122.aspx?HTTP+1+1+405+Method+Not+Allowed+Allow+OPTIONS+TRACE+GET+HEAD](https://forums.iis.net/t/1152122.aspx?HTTP%201%201%20405%20Method%20Not%20Allowed%20Allow%20OPTIONS%20TRACE%20GET%20HEAD)

I simply added a trailing slash on my method name. 
I have the Endpoint set  to the xxx.svc. 
Then I had the Resource set to a value such as /Resource1. 
By changing it to /Resource1/ it worked.

The above link suggests that it tries to read the directory or something.

Comment: It may not have had anything to do with the SSL, I found an older screen shot where I had the / at the end.